# Input KMZ files into leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, kml, kmz

Is it possible to input a zipped .kml file (.kmz) int Leaflet?

I was trying the code:

```
fetch('Cov.kmz')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })
```

But it doesn't appear on the map at all.

There is the plugin for that:

https://github.com/engrabid411/kmzol3

which doesn't work for the time being.

I also found an advice here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147510/kml-layer-fetch-error

But to be honest, extracting .kmz file into .kml and another ones, comprising of the .kmz file not help me enough.

Comment: What error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error itself. Simply code isn't working.

Comment: No network errors, even? Add a [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) and inspect the values of `kmltext` and `track`, see if everything looks like it should. Add a [`catch` branch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) for error handling as well.

Comment: Could you write it down for me as an example? I am not perfect in this coding so far I am afraid. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-kmz  This might work.